# Oracle schema migration using OEM CC 12c

Tags: database, oracle, grid, migration, schema

Is there a way to migrate an oracle database schema between database targets in the oracle enterprise manager cloud control 12c?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Targets -> Databases -> Select source database... 
...-> Schema -> Database Export/Import -> Export to Export Files ... follow instructions

Targets -> Databases -> Select target database... 
...-> Schema -> Database Export/Import -> Import from Export Files ... follow instructions

:p

Comment: Thanks! But I asked for a bit more graceful way))